# Is it possible to combine coroutines and templates from `<algorithm>` header?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++-coroutine

I write a lot of TCP/IP based C++ software, and I use modern C++ coroutines for network communications. Now let suppose I have array of URLs, and I want to find which URL downloads document that contains "Hello" string:

```
vector<string> my_urls = { /* URLs list here */ };
auto hello_iterator = find_if(my_urls.begin(), my_urls.end(), [](const string &url) 
{ 
    string downloaded_data = download(url);
    return downloaded_data.find("Hello") != string::npos;
});
```

Here we use synchronous `download(const std::string& url)` function to download data for each URL.

With coroutines I want to do something similar:

```
vector<string> my_urls = { /* URLs list here */ };
auto hello_iterator = find_if(my_urls.begin(), my_urls.end(), [](const string &url) -> MyPromiseClass
{ 
    string downloaded_data = co_await async_download(url);
    return downloaded_data.find("Hello") != string::npos;
});
```

I have `MyPromiseClass async_download(const std::string& url)` that works nice, and I want to use it to download data asynchronously.

But such code doesn't compile. In Visual C++ I have following error:

> error C2451: a conditional expression of type 'MyPromiseClass' is not
> valid

The reason is that standard `find_if` algorithm "doesn't know" about coroutines and simply tries to convert `MyPromiseClass` to `bool`.

I however can easily implement coroutine version of `find_if` and/or any other standard algorithm that will work by just changing its `if` statement to one that uses `co_await` when calls predicate and returns promise instead of iterator, so I hope that C++ standard should also contain similar algorithms?

Please advise are there any version of `<algorithm>` header in C++ standard or `boost` that supports coroutines, or are there any way to easily convert "old" algorithms from `<aglorithm>` header to support coroutines without manual rewriting them or ugly code that first precalculates values (with coroutines) and later uses algorithms on these precalculated values instead of just awaiting data in lambda expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only coroutines can call `co_await`, but the standard algorithms aren't coroutines (and one can argue that they shouldn't be). This means that you can't pass a coroutine into a standard algorithm and expect it to wait for its result.

If the standard algorithms were coroutines, you couldn't just call them and get their result - instead, they'd all return futures or coroutine types that you'd have to wait on before proceeding, similar to how your `async_download` function doesn't return a `std::string` directly, but rather some kind of custom future. As a result, the standard algorithms would be really difficult to use in anything *but* a coroutine. This would be necessary because any coroutines passed into a standard algorithm could suspend themselves, which in turn means that the algorithm itself would have to be able to suspend itself, making it a coroutine.

Note that a coroutine "suspending" means that the coroutine saves its state to its coroutine frame and then *returns*. If you need this to work across multiple levels of the call stack, every function in that part of the call stack has to be in on the joke and be able to *return early* when a coroutine somewhere down the line decides to suspend. Coroutines can trivially do this via `co_await`, and you can also write code that does this manually by i.e. returning a future.

Since the standard algorithms return plain values, and not futures, they can't return early and therefore don't support suspension. As a result, they can't call coroutines.

What you could do instead is to download the data first, and then search for the string:

```
std::vector<std::string> urls = ...;
std::vector<MyPromiseClass> downloads;

//Start downloading everything in parallel
std::transform(urls.begin(), urls.end(),
               std::back_insert_iterator(downloads), async_download);

std::vector<std::string> data;

//Wait for all downloads
for (auto& promise: downloads) {
    data.push_back(co_await promise);
}

auto hello_iterator = std::find_if(data.begin(), data.end(), ...);
```

If you wanted to, you could create a helper function (templated coroutine) that `co_awaits` multiple awaitable objects and returns their results.

Comment: I see that standard algorithms are not coroutines, but why did they not add theirs coroutine versions? `find_if_async`, etc...? `<algorithm>` header is widely used in C++ code, and lack of new feature support is painful. It was OK to use callbacks to create asynchronous code in past, but coroutines appeared to simplify life, and `co_await` is much better than tons of callbacks, but if they are incompatible with so basic language feature, theirs use is a bit limited; a lot of custom implementations of missing feature may appear, and C++ will not have standard way to perform a very common task.

Comment: @Vitalii Probably the same reason there's no built-in coroutine promise type. They rushed to add the core language feature, so the library developers can start experimenting with it. And the standard library can [ship the supporting code later](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/generator).

Answer (score 0):

Suspending directly from a nested function call is a property of so-called "stackful coroutines", while the C++20 coroutines are "stackless" (meaning, you can only suspend in the function body).

[Boost.Coroutine2](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/coroutine2/doc/html/coroutine2/coroutine.html) provides stackful coroutines, and there might be other libraries too.